# Custom object class in java - looks puzzle

Tags: java, eclipse

Just as a try I thought of creating a explicit `Object` class in my project under my own package **`java.lang`**. First surprise is eclipse allows me to create a `Object` class.
My class looks as shown below

```
public class Object {
    public void add(){
        System.out.println("Inside add");  
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Inside display");
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to write a Test class as below

```
public class Test {

    @Override
    public void add() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.add();
    }
    @Override
    public void display() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.display();
    }
}
```

Here all the `Object` class methods are not visible but only the methods which I created in my Object class are visible.

My doubt is why it didn't refer to JDK's Object class? Can anyone explain this and what happen to Object class in JDK package in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the Object class is refereeing to your own Object class. You are free to create with name of Object as the package is different to the jdk's Object class.

In short, *though the class name is same, they are differnt with package names*.

Now just change your import to `java.lang.Object` and see the result:) It refers to JDK's Object class.

If package name is also same, when you run your code you'll see

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, package name is also same like in Object class for my custom Object class.

Comment: @Krishna You can use the getClass().getCanonicalName() to view which Object Class you are calling

Comment: @Beginner Since its a my own Object class I don't have getClass() method.

Comment: @Krishna Just run your program. You can'y :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class Test without extending any other class, it is implicitly converted to the following:

```
 class Test extends java.lang.Object {
 ...
 }
```

Since in your project you have a `java.lang.Object`, the `Test` class is accessing it. That is why none of the other methods from standard Object are visible.

That said, why are you doing it?